# Specflow - [BeforeTestRun] and [AfterTestRun] are not being executed

Tags: c#, testing, binding, automated-tests, specflow

My `[BeforeTestRun]` and `[AfterTestRun]` bindings are not being executed,
while the `[BeforeScenario]`, `[AfterStep]` and `[AfterScenario]` is being executed.

From this class the first binding that is executed is `[BeforeScenario]`. I am kind of clueless why the `[BeforeTestRun]` and `[AfterTestRun]` are being ignored.

#### Code with `BeforeTestRunAttribute`

```cs
[BeforeTestRun]
public static void TestInitialize()
{
    var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"D:\\ExtentReport\\");
    extent = new AventStack.ExtentReports.ExtentReports();
    extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
}
```

#### Code with `AfterTestRunAttribute`

```cs
[AfterTestRun]
public static void CleanUp()
{
    extent.Flush();
}
```

While this code (`[AfterStep]` and `[BeforeScenario]`) is being executed:

#### Code with `BeforeScenarioAttribute`

```cs
[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    InitializeSettings();
    featureName = extent.CreateTest<Feature>(_featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
    scenario = featureName.CreateNode<Scenario>(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
}
```

#### Code with `AfterStepAttribute`

```cs
[AfterStep]
public void InsertReportingSteps()
{
    var stepName = _scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text;
    var featureName = _featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title;
    var scenarioName = _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title;

    var stepType = _scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();

    if (_scenarioContext.TestError == null)
        .....[etc..]
}
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why my `BeforeTestRun` and `AfterTestRun` bindings are not being executed?
All bindings are in the same `HookInitialize.cs` class.

- Specflow version 3.4.8
- Specflow.NUnit version 3.4.8
- NUnit version 3.12.0
- NUnit3TestAdapter version 3.17.0

Comment: Did you set the MSBuild property GenerateSpecFlowAssemblyHooksFile somewhere to false?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no. I don't have <GenerateSpecFlowAssemblyHooksFile> mentioned in my *.csproj file.

Comment: Could you create a small project where the issue is reproducable? The MSbuild property was the quick idea, but without more information, I can't say what the reason is.

Comment: Well it's quite a small framework which is implemented so in that sense it's not that it is already huge at the moment. Only thing is that there is also functionality like parallel execution added. But to my knowledge that should not affect this part.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? Experiencing the same issue after refactoring our solution (so it used to work) but no idea why...

Comment: Did you put the [Binding] attributes above the class declarations containing the [BeforeTestRun] / [AfterTestRun] code? I had the same issue, before I discovered I forgot to add the [Binding] attribute. Without the binding attribute, [AfterFeature] and [AfterTestRun] did not work, but [AfterScenario] did.

Answer (score -1):

Nunit uses [OneTimeSetup], [OneTimeTearDown] etc maybe check that out. I have a very limited knowledge when it comes to specflow but in general I would stick to bindings from one framework if possible.

Comment: You don't use the NUnit attributes in SpecFlow. We have hooks for that, that integrate in all the different test runners. Using this attributes breaks stuff in the SpecFlow runtime. Don't use them!